# Odoo 9 page Not opening properly

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-9

Even after following the instruction on installing Odoo 9 on a virtual environment, The odoo page cannot open properly components are not loading.

```
`2018-12-03 08:22:42,213 5837 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 9.0c
2018-12-03 08:22:42,214 5837 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: 
['/home/benora/.local/share/Odoo/addons/9.0', 
u'/home/benora/Odoo/Odoo9/openerp/addons', 
u'/home/benora/Odoo/Odoo9/addons']
2018-12-03 08:22:42,215 5837 INFO ? openerp: database: 
default@default:default
2018-12-03 08:22:43,003 5837 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service 
(werkzeug) running on ubuntu:8069
2018-12-03 08:22:53,622 5837 INFO ? openerp.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop 
listen imbus on db postgres
2018-12-03 08:22:57,143 5837 INFO ? openerp.addons.report.models.report: 
Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
2018-12-03 08:23:03,616 5837 INFO ? openerp.http: HTTP Configuring static 
files
2018-12-03 08:23:03,925 5837 INFO test openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 
modules...
2018-12-03 08:23:03,982 5837 INFO test openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules 
loaded in 0.06s, 0 queries
2018-12-03 08:23:04,394 5837 INFO test openerp.modules.loading: loading 37 
modules...
2018-12-03 08:23:05,009 5837 INFO test openerp.modules.loading: 37 modules 
loaded in 0.61s, 0 queries
2018-12-03 08:23:08,873 5837 INFO test openerp.modules.loading: Modules 
loaded.
2018-12-03 08:23:08,891 5837 INFO test openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_http: 
Generating routing map
2018-12-03 08:23:12,421 5837 INFO test werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2018 
08:23:12] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2018-12-03 08:23:13,077 5837 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2018 
08:23:13] "GET /web/static/src/css/full.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2018-12-03 08:23:13,231 5837 INFO test openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_attachment:
```

_read_file reading
/home/benora/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/test/95/95097e93490667181820c38925d2138d375fca2b
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/benora/Odoo/Odoo9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_attachment.py", line 
   105, in _file_read
    r = open(full_path,'rb').read().encode('base64')
   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: `

`u'/home/benora/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/test/95/95097e93490667181820c38925d2138d375fca2b'`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you restored a database you should know that odoo store attachments in this file

```
      .../filestore/database_name/
```

Like images or compressed file for backend so what you need to do is copy the original files from your previous file store to the new one.

Or access the base in debug mode and delete `ir.attachment` record of backend (.css,.js)

Access the url like this.

```
     ipaddress:port/web?debug=
```

Now go to

```
   setting -> database structure -> attachements
```

And delete attachment related to backend filter them and delete them. This will force odoo to recreate them again